# jquery grab html from closest div with given class

Tags: jquery

I have a button that is embedded within a number of divs. When I press the button I want to move some of the html in one of these higher level divs. I however can't seem to be able to select the content of the div.

In the example below I want to select and show the html inside the div with class *classB* 'belonging' to the *classA container* that contains the button pressed.

html

```
<div id="myList">

  <div class="classA">

    <div class="classB">
      <p>content 1</p>
    </div>

    <div class="classC">
      <button class="myButton">
        I am a button
      </button>
    </div>

  </div>


  <div class="classA">

    <div class="classB">
      <p>content 2</p>
    </div>

    <div class="classC">
      <button class="myButton">
        I am a button
      </button>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('#myList').on('click','.myButton', function(event){
    alert($(this).parents().parents().html());

    alert($(this).parents().parents('.classB').html());

    alert($(this).closest('.classB').html());
  });

});
```

and a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/6jd0sp1j/18/

The second and third alerts keep returning undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `$(this).parent().prev().html()`

`$(this)` - This is the button clicked.

`$(this).parent()` - This will return the parent of the button, which is `div.classC`

`$(this).parent().prev()` - Will return the prev element of the parent, which is `div.classB`

Example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myList').on('click', '.myButton', function(event) {
    console.log($(this).parent().prev().html());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myList">
  <div class="classA">
    <div class="classB">
      <p>content 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="classC">
      <button class="myButton">
        I am a button
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="classA">
    <div class="classB">
      <p>content 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="classC">
      <button class="myButton">
        I am a button
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**Note:** In debugging, please use `console.log` instead of `alert`